# Missing asyncValidator on initing input (Angular 7.0.1)

Tags: angular, angular7

Just upgraded to Angular 7.0.1 and faced weird behavior with formControl's asyncValidator (i have asyncValidator directive linked to my formControl).

On initing component with input which has asyncValidator directive, i don't have asyncValidator linked to my formControl, but in validator fires "validate" function (that collected errors)!!

[image: no asyncValidator on formControl]
[image: collected error but asyncValidator does not have them]

After component initing and changing value of input (with this formControl) asyncValidator magically appears and everything works as expected.

[image: asyncValidator magically appears]

Problem is that on init input's erros doesn't displayed when was calculated and added to from control.

In Angular version 6+ everything was fine!

Look at screenshots.

Does anybody faced same issue?

Comment: Please show us your code as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, Angular 6+ behaves the same but shows validation errors. Forget to mention, i'm using "OnPush" strategy.

On Angular 6+ :

1. on component initing fires "statusChanges" event of "formControl" with status "Valid", without linked "asyncValidator"
2. after this "validate" function is called in my directive ("asyncValidator"), that collect errors
3. when component view inited with empty input, input has "invalid" underline and expected errors

On Angular 7+ :

1-2. the same behavior

3. input appears without "invalid" underline and errors till not focused, when it was touched (focused) - error appears :\

This is my "asyncValidate" directive:

```js
@Input()
public propertyName: string;

private get _businessObject(): BusinessBase {
    return this._fieldComponentBase.businessObject;
}

private _propertyChangedSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private _fieldComponentBase: FieldComponentBase) {}

public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribeFromPropertyChangedEvent();
}

public validate(abstractControl: FormControl): Promise<ValidationErrors> | Observable<ValidationErrors> {
    if (!this.propertyName) {
        throw new Error('Property name of business object was not provided.');
    }

    if (!this._businessObject) {
        throw new Error('Business object was not provided.');
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const errors: ValidationErrors = {};

        if (this._businessObject.shouldPristineFormControl(this.propertyName)) {
            abstractControl.markAsPristine();


     this._businessObject.removePropertyFormControlPristineStatus(this.propertyName);
        }

        if (abstractControl.dirty) {
            this.unsubscribeFromPropertyChangedEvent();

            this._propertyChangedSubscription = this._businessObject.propertyChanged
                .subscribe((propertyChangedEvent: PropertyChangedEvent) => {
                    if (propertyChangedEvent.propertyName !== this.propertyName) {
                        return;
                    }

                    this.unsubscribeFromPropertyChangedEvent();

                    this.setErrors(errors);

                    resolve(errors);
                });
        } else {
            this.setErrors(errors);

            resolve(errors);
        }
    });
}

private setErrors(errors: ValidationErrors) {
    this._businessObject.getBrokenRules(undefined, this.propertyName).forEach((brokenRule, index) => {
        errors[index] = brokenRule.message;
    });
}

private unsubscribeFromPropertyChangedEvent() {
    if (!this._propertyChangedSubscription) {
        return;
    }

    this._propertyChangedSubscription.unsubscribe();

    this._propertyChangedSubscription = undefined;
}
```

This is my "statusChanges" listener of form control:

```js
this.formControl.statusChanges.subscribe((status: 'VALID' | 'INVALID' | 'PENDING') => {
        if (!this._formControlStatus) {
            this._formControlStatus = status;

            return;
        }

        if (status === 'PENDING' || status === 'VALID' && status === this._formControlStatus) {
            return;
        }

        this._formControlStatus = status;

        /**
         * Should update component bindings if error calculation took too long.
         */
        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after small workaround figured only this solution:

```js
        if (!this._formControlStatus) {
            this._formControlStatus = status;

            /**
             * Should update component bindings after small timeout on first init.
             *
             * Otherwise validation (if exists) will not be desplayed untill focusing input.
             */
            timer(1).subscribe(() => {
                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            });

            return;
        }
```

If id don't have cashed "_formControlStatus" - means that input with from control was init first time and evaluating "detectChanges" after short delay will update view with input :\